# how to access the child object in sqlalchemy

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

Can someone please help

```
subscription = session.get(SubscriptionModel, 1)
print(subscription.customer)
```

this print the id of the customer but how do I get the customer object?

Comment: Please include your data model for ` SubscriptionModel`. Specifically the way in which you defined `customer`.

Answer (score 0):

You have to define your data model to include a relationship to the other class. Somthing like this should do it

```
class subscription (Base):
    __tablename__ = 'subscription'
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    customer_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('subscription_model.id'))

    customer = relationship("SubscriptionModel", foreign_keys=customer_id )
```

Then you will have the object instead of the id:

```
subscription = session.query(SubscriptionModel).get(1)
print(subscription.customer_id) # ID
print(subscription.customer)    # Object
```